# Как включить поддержку Webp в Wordpress без плагинов?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, webp

Как включить поддержку изображений в формате Webp в Wordpress? А именно, чтоб можно было добавлять изображения товаров в Woocommerce из админки в формате Webp. Может есть какая-то функция для включения Webp в function.php.

Comment: Начиная с версии 5.8, WordPress поддерживает WebP из коробки.

Comment: Разработчики отказались включать по умолчанию формат WebP в WordPress 6.1

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в functions.php

```
//** Включение формата .webp./
 function webp_upload_mimes($existing_mimes) {
 $existing_mimes['webp'] = 'image/webp';
 return $existing_mimes;
 }
 add_filter('mime_types', 'webp_upload_mimes');
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но WordPress действительно поддерживает .webp из коробки. Проблема была с локальным сервером XAMPP, именно он не пропускал формат .webp